# Upgrade from Rails 3.0 to 3.1 and then to 3.2 - but keep 3.0 working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade

I have 3.0.5 rails apps and they are getting older.
I'm planning the upgrade to Rails 3.2

The guides recommend to go first from 3.0 to 3.1 and then to 3.2 so
that's what I will try.

But while I do the upgrade I want to keep the projects fully working and
probably even do some pushes to production with the current 3.0.5 apps.

So basically I want to do the upgrades in parallel without disturbing
the real apps.

I will use the same machine running Snow Leopard.

I use RVM for Ruby management.

Any recommendations how to setup this parallel upgrade? Is git branching
actually an option, would so many potential changes fit in the concept of Git branch?

Thanks

Comment: I had a git branch called "rails-31" for my migration from 3.0 to 3.1 and the same for 3.2. Worked fine for me. Plus I had a stable branch which was deployed every day and where Bugfixes and minor improvements belongs to. Mergin master/stable back to the "rails-31" branch was pretty easy. Just my experience that git-branching was fine for me for that task.

Comment: Thanks a lot Deradon! I will do the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitively use git branches. A possible good git workflow would be this one:

> - Let's assume that your **Master** branch is currently on Rails 3.0.x and it's in production.
> - From this master branch, you create 2 branches: **rails_30, rails_31.**
> - You start working in the **rails_31** branch with all the necessary changes needed for upgrading to Rails 3.1.x (This screencast from Ryan Bates will help you a lot: http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1 )
> - When you are done migrating to Rails 3.1.x (hint: all your tests passing) you can create a new **rails_32** branch from this one. Then you can continue to upgrade to Rails 3.2.x (check out this other railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2 )
> - When you need to introduce changes to your current Rails 3.0.x code base, you will work on the **rails_30** branch. If a change is good to go and tested, you can push it to master. Once this is pushed you can either try to merge or cherry pick code this branch to your **rails_31** or **rails_32** branch (whichever you are working with at this point in time)

*Remember that upgrading Rails apps it's not always a trivial task*, so take you time & plan accordingly. If you get stucked; a gem is not supported, you logic fails in a newer version of Rails (*believe it will most probably happen*) Just remember that the Ruby on Rails community is huge, many developers have passed through this before and have share their knowledge in stackoverflow and other sites/blogs. Just keep pushing play.

*Good Luck.*

Comment: Thanks, I should have selected the right answer before. Yours and Deradon explanations a good. Yes I ended using branches and so far compatibility has been ok.